# Facebook Api Marketing : (#3) Application does not have the capability to make this API call

Tags: facebook, authorization, access-token, facebook-marketing-api

I got this error, when I am logging with facebook

```
"(#3) Application does not have the capability to make this API call."
```

Because it's work when I use my account, but when I use test account, it doesn't work ...
It's possible to set  permissions ads_read, ads_management in the code Facebook api SDK Javascript ?

With the same token I am able to correctly call the API to get a list of all adaccounts `(GET-> /v2.12/me/adaccounts )`

Anyone have an idea what my issue might be?

Comment: It’s not possible to “set” permissions, but you can _ask_ for them, and yes, that can be done using the JS SDK as well (as it is part of the general login process.)

Comment: How can I do to set permissions for each time ads_read & ads_management ? I have only a facebook account developper, and in the interface I can set ads_read & ads_management, but for an another account who is in app, he can't logged, because we don't set permissions.

Comment: _You_ need to implement the login flow, if you want other people to be able to log into your app and grant it permissions.

Comment: We run into the same issue. In our case we ask only for ads_read permission. Any idea if we should also ask for ads_management?